# How to change shell and execute some command in .profile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, .profile

My requirement is that when I log-in into Linux, I should be able to change the default shell, initialize some variables and remain in new shell.

I put below commands inside ".profile" file but it is just changing the default shell to bash and not running any subsequent commands:

```
bash
alias tl='ls -ltr | tail'
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

Comment: Changing the default shell is done by updating your entry in `/etc/passwd` (or whichever other directory service is in use), not by configuration in your dotfiles. Your operating system will provide a command such as `usermod` for making this change; you'll need to check its documentation to see exactly what the command is there, as it varies between operating systems and distirbutions.

Comment: Use `chsh` for changing your shell. Also, if you `exit` bash, your commands on the next two lines will be executed.

Comment: Regardless, a question about OS-level configuration is not a question about programming. Consider http://superuser.com/, or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Come on guys, lets cut BhushanD some slack. The `.profile` contents shown *is a program* and being unaware of the result of running bash from its profile is reasonably on-topic here.

Comment: @Jens, yes, the .profile is a program, but "how do I change my default shell?" is clearly OS-level configuration. If the problem centered on the use of bash as a programming language even in the context of `.profile`, I'd have no problem with it whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You should not start `bash` as the first thing. What do you expect this to do?

Remove that line and the alias and `PS1` setting will work.

If the default shell is not bash, but you want it to be, **and** you can't use `chsh` for lack of permission, then find the particular profile and place

```
exec /path/to/bash -l
```

at the top and you'll get a bash login shell. (Which then probably sources `.bashrc` or `.profile` or whatever it was configured to source).

Comment: I'd suggest a conditional to prevent any chance of a loop, ie. `[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || exec /path/to/bash -l`. That said, this *is* a good answer, even if I take issue with the question. :)

Comment: That said, remove that line and the alias will work _for login shells_; to work for other shells it may need to be set in `.rc` instead, as evaluation of `.profile` is conditional.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy These are good points!